# asp.net routing cannot find method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a folder crated in my application called admin inside the controllers, so my folder structure looks like this

```
-Models
|
-Views
|
-Controller
  |
  |-HomeController.cs
  |
  |-Admin
     |
     |-HomeController.cs <-- in this controller, i have methods Add,Delete,View
```

i needed to created a route so if i type the url `http://localhost:2336/admin/add`, it will execute the add method of the home controller, but i get a 404 error.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "fms.Controllers.Admin" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin route specifies a route like this:

```
Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

This means in your URL you need to have the controller name as well as the action. For example, this should work:

```
http://localhost:2336/admin/home/add
```

If you change the url route to this it will work:

```
Admin/{action}/{id}
```

However, this does mean it's a little pointless to have your admin controller in it's own folder. If I were you I'd look up how to create a new MVC area.

Comment: I am getting this error `Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'.`

Comment: You probably need to specify a namespace for your other route then. Or use an area which makes all this go away :)

Comment: i already did `fms.Controllers.Admin` or are you talking about the default routes